# Firefox extension startup notification

Tags: firefox-addon, observer-pattern

I am having trouble following the explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM/Receiving_startup_notifications) about receiving startup notifications in a Firefox extension.  It says there to add

```
category profile-after-change MyComponent @foobar/mycomponent;1
```

to chrome.manifest.  What do I put for `MyComponent` and `foobar/mycomponent;1`?

My extension is actually a plugin for another extension.  In its main .js file, I have

```
MainExtension.MyPlugin = {...
```

and then define all of my functions inside of my MyPlugin object property of the MainExtension's object.

I believe that I should set `MyComponent` to `MainExtension.MyPlugin`.  I am not sure about the second part.  I am also not sure what I need to do to call the function that I want called on start up.  Looking at some other extensions, I think I might need to add an `observe()` method to `MainExtension.MyPlugin` that calls another function when it receives a `profile-after-change` notification, but I am not sure.

Comment: How do you load that "main .js file"? Via a `<script>` tag in an overlay or something else? The documentation talks about XPCOM components but you apparently don't have one.

Comment: In include.js, mozIJSSubScriptLoader is used to load the main .js file, and that file defines `MainExtension.MyPlugin` and then ends with `window.addEventListener('load', function(e) { MainExtension.MyPlugin.init(); }, false);`.  I based my plugin off [this sample plugin](https://github.com/zotero/zotero-hello-world), but that plugin seems out of date because it uses "requires" in install.rdf which is no longer supported.  I wanted to change to using profile-after-change to replace the "requires" functionality.

Comment: In other words - the script is being loaded by an overlay (indirectly).

Comment: I am also hoping to fix a bug in my plugin that I think might be related ([code here](https://github.com/willsALMANJ/Zutilo)).  Zotero can be set to load as another pane in the browser, as a separate tab, or as an app tab.  When Zotero loads as a pane in the browser, my plugin works, but when it loads in another tab my plugin does not overlay its XUL (neither through .xul files nor through code within zutilo.js).  My plugin does still load properly though, because I can access its preferences/functions via Add-ons Manager.  Maybe if my plugin observed Zotero properly, the overlay would work?

Comment: Okay, so I need to make my extension an XPCOM component to get a profile-after-change notification, but maybe @paa's suggestion of AddonManager is better for what I want to do (create a plugin that is loaded onto another extension)?

Comment: I think Wladimir Palant's two comments together are the best answer to my question.  I would accept them as the answer if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wladimir Palant noted in a comment to the question, to use the profile-after-change notification you have to have an XPCOM component.  Then `MyComponent` is the class that component creates and `@foobar/mycomponent;1` is the component's contract id.  I didn't know what these were because my extension simply overlays another extension that defines an XPCOM component.  My extension doesn't have its own XPCOM component.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you actually want is to get notified when the MainExtension is available. Try the [AddonManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager)

Comment: AddonManager seems promising, but I am having trouble following the syntax.  I think I want to import AddonManager and then do `AddonManager.addAddonListener()` and use an `onEnabled()` listener, but I am not sure how to define this listener for MainExtension for passing to `AddonManager.addAddonListener()`.  Also, where would I define this listener?  Right now, my plugin is being defined by an overlay (see discussion above), but maybe this listener needs to be defined when I create my extension as an XPCOM component (which I currently don't do -- I just overlay and extend the existing one).

Comment: I played around with the AddonManager a bit and figured out how to add listeners....  However, it seems that AddonManager only lets you add listeners for when add-ons are enabled/disabled and installed/uninstalled, not for when they become available during a normal Firefox launch.

Comment: Okay, what I said above is true about listeners, but I will say that I have found AddonManager.getAddonByID() very useful for running some code that requires MainExtension to be installed.  Thanks for the suggestions!